# Using ranked results to perform calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using excel 2013 and have the following fields:

Column B  - value used as an input to calculate Gain based on Rank
Column C - Rank which will be keyed in by user (1 being the first rank)
Column D - Gain (the actual value calculated based on Rank, see below formula)

General formula for Gain is the product of values in column B, subject to the ranking input.
e.g.
`if RANK = 1`, '40%' is converted to '100%' and `Gain = 100%*50%*0%*20%*90%*10%`.
`if RANK = 2`, '50%' is converted to '100%' and `Gain =  100%*100%%*0%*20%*90%*10%` (the values in all preceding rankings are taken to be '100%')

Can it be done via formula? It looks quite daunting and I am not sure if using SORT will help? I'm trying to avoid VBA if possible, but if it's really required, then VBA it shall be.

```
Item #  Value   Rank    Gain    How to calculate Gain?
A       90%     5       10%     100%*100%*100%*100%*100%*10% = 10%
B       0%      3       1.8%    100%*100%*100%*20%*90%*10%  = 1.8%
C       40%     1       0%      100%*50%*0%*20%*90%*10% = 0%
D       50%     2       0%      100%*100%*0%*20%*90%*10% = 0%
E       10%     6       100%    100%*100%*100%*100%*100%*100%  = 100%
F       20%     4       9.00%   100%*100%*100%*100%*90%*10%  = 9%
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the following formula in D2 as a array formula and fill down.

```
{=PRODUCT(IF($C$2:$C$7<=C2,100%,$B$2:$B$7))}
```

To create an array formula insert the formula in the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]. The curly brackets will then appear automatically.